# Insert space after pattern matches and replace pattern with other word

Tags: awk, sed

How can I insert space after pattern matches

File has data

```
cellAN2D
input a1
output z
cellAIOI2D2
input a2
output z2
cellXOR2
input b1
output zn
```

Whenever pattern is found I want to add space after it. And output will be

```
cell AN2D
input a1
output z
cell AIOI2D2
input a2
output z
cell XOR2
input b1
output z
```

I tried

```
sed  's/^cell/cell /g' file
```

But it did not work.

Further I want to replace the cell word in above output to module word giving output

```
module AN2D
input a1
output z
module AIOI2D2
input a2
output z
module XOR2
input b1
output z
```

Can i combine both steps together to get final output.

Comment: Your `sed` command is fine and is working as expected. For the modification you want, you have to just modify to `'s/^cell/module /g'`. If you have a case where your command didn't work, update the question with that case, adding the specific output you get (not only "it did not work" because this phrase alone is not helpful)

Comment: I am not getting any output using above sed command

Comment: Right. Because you use `-i` which means `sed` to do any changes in-place, so there is no output into the console, you edit directly the file. `man sed` for details.

Comment: when I used the command ```sed 's/^cell /module /g' file``` then also I am getting back my original file, cell is not replaced by module word nor did there is space after cell.

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY. That is the expected behavior. Are you looking for both output to console and a changed file?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you said @fpmurphy yes I want both outputs to be reflect in file. But using ```sed /^cell / module /g' file``` I am not getting

Comment: ```cell``` is at start of line. Actual file is also same as one in question. To be more precise with input file i have editted the question. Can we do it in other way like searching for cell word in each line and if it is present add space after cell and replace it with module word. So when it encounter ```cellAN2D``` , we get ```module AN2D``` similarly for rest or in two way process ```cell AN2D``` then ```module AN2D```

Comment: This ```s/^cell/cell``` also worked. There was space error in code. Now resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$ sed 's/^cell/module /' file | tee outfile && mv outfile file
module AN2D
input
output
module AIOI2D2
input
output
module XOR2
input
output

$ cat file
module AN2D
input
output
module AIOI2D2
input
output
module XOR2
input
output
$
```

Comment: @steeldriver. True. Modified answer.